# Can an ios app support just 9.7 inch iPad and not 12.9 iPad Pro device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad app which is supported on iPad (9.7 inches).
I want to update my app on the app store, but now they have added the support for 12.9 inches iPad Pro as well.
And while uploading the app, I got app submission errors which basically was asking for adding the screenshot for 12.9 inches iPad Pro too.

I have not tested my app on iPad Pro yet and I want to update the App first.
So my question is that Can I choose to pick iPad (regular) as my support Device and not iPad Pro (at-least for now)? If yes, then how?

I can see the setting in Xcode to pick between iPhone/iPad/Universal App, but could not find any way to configure iPad Pro as unsupported Device in Xcode or itunesconnect portal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible - sort of. But it means that you must use launch images and not a launch screen file. Once you are setup to use launch images, simply don't provide launch images for the iPad Pro.

Your app will still run on the iPad Pro but it will be scaled to fit the larger screen. As far as your app is concerned, it will think it is running on any other iPad.

But honestly, this isn't really a good plan. Take a few minutes and run your app on an iPad Pro (or simulator) and see if it works or not. Take the time to make it work. Your users will be much happier.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I eventually tried out my app in simulator on iPadPro. Though, I am not very happy with how it is looking on larger screen, but at-least UI is not broken.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, as you mentioned yourself that Xcode allows you to pick between iPhone/iPad/Universal App and that true.
Currently, apple does not allow to discontinue app for the specific device, neither from Xcode settings nor iTunes settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I could not find any way to do this either. I ended up testing my app on iPad Pro (on simulator) and publish the app for both small n large iPads.